Can't drop role due to dependencies

I'm new to Postgres, and I want to delete a role named rp_ts04, but it complains about dependencies. I don't know how to check for these dependencies.
I've checked information_schema but it doesn't show any relation to rp_ts04.
Can anyone give me a hint in this case?

Sorry for late response! Having troubleshooted and I find a way out by using:
SQL> REVOKE SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA information_schema FROM rp_ts04;

Thank you: Erwin Brandstetter & tax evader for your precious support!

DROP OWNED does not exactly sound like it would revoke privileges granted to a role, but it does. As it also drops objects owned by the role, the safe sequence of commands to drop a role is:
REASSIGN OWNED BY rp_ts04 TO placeholder_role;  -- some trusted role
DROP OWNED BY rp_ts04;

It's not either-or. Only DROP OWNED removes granted privileges.
Your error message points to privileges, not ownership. REASSIGN OWNED won't fix that.
Run this in all databases of the same cluster where the role might own anything or have been granted privileges. Roles are shared between all databases in the same cluster. Then a final:
DROP ROLE rp_ts04;

See:

Cannot drop PostgreSQL role. Error: `cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it`


Thanks for your solution. The transfer of objects takes place implicitly! Is it possible that I can figure out dependent objects and revoking manually?

The list you see in the error msg. is already what you are looking for. If your error msg is complete, no objects will be "transferred". It's all about privileges, which will be revoked. Else you would see: owner of table ...

If I run REASSIGN from rp_test04 to postgres. Is is affect functionality of PostgreSQL DB? Due to those dependencies seems to be built-in object of postgresql?

@Duong: There should not be any grants to objects of the information schema to begin with. But you have them (for whatever reason?), so you need to get rid of them. Getting rid of those gets you back to normal.

Also, once more: DROP OWNED removes granted privileges. REASSIGN OWNED is just for safety, to transfer ownerships if any. If there are none, the command does nothing.

From DROP ROLE documentation, looks like a role cannot be removed if it is still referenced in somewhere in the database, so you would need to drop all the objects owned by that role using DROP OWNED
DROP OWNED BY rp_ts04;

or re-asign them to other role using REASSIGN OWNED
REASSIGN OWNED BY rp_ts04 TO <new role>;


Thanks for your reply but I'm still facing a little concern. The referenced objects seems relating to built-in Postgres (information_schema). I'm not confident in deleting them. And reassign will leave "garbage" in DB. My concern is how to determine dependencies relating to those View (in the image) and revoke them!
